# Looping Through Different Text Files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hi I am trying to make an overall for loop for this bit of code so I can loop through different text files that have a similar name and run that code each time for each text file. For some reason though it is saying that student_input and professor_input is "command not found".

Here are other instructions for the project that I also need to do:
Update master table of grades (up to 15 additional points): Instead of writing the grades of the current homework in a new file, add a column to an existing table which contains the grades of the past homework (one row per student, one column per past homework). You might want to investigate the command paste
• Partial grades (up to 15 additional points): Instead of giving only 0 or 1, the instructor would like to give partial credit to those submissions that are partly correct. You might want to investigate the command diff.

If someone could help me with these it would be a ton of help!

```
#!/bin/bash

student_input="/home/dtoda/finalproj/studentanswer.txt"

professor_input="/home/dtoda/professoranswer.txt"

score=0

for filename in /home/dtoda/finalproj/*.txt
do

        paste -d ":" $(student_input) $(professor_input) | while IFS=":" read -r line

        do
                stu_ans=$(echo $line | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
                eval $stu_ans > student_output.txt

                prof_ans=$(echo $line | awk -F":" '{print $2}')
                eval $prof_ans > professor_output.txt

                if diff professor_output.txt student_output.txt
                then
                        echo correct
                        score=$((score + 1))
                else
                        echo incorrect
                fi

                echo Score: $score
        done
done
```

Comment: Remove the parenthesis from `$(student_input) $(professor_input)` ,e.g. `"$student_input" "$professor_input"`  `$(...)` is for *Command Substitution*. Always quote your variables. Also remember `eval` is just one letter different than `evil`. Perhaps `diff -q`? Since you hare using bash, you could do `while IFS=":" read -r line; do ... done < <(paste -d ":" "$student_input" "$professor_input")`

Comment: Additionally, everything you are doing can be done in a single call to `awk`. Any time you find yourself calling any utility in a loop (which spawns multiple subshells every iteration), it's generally time to take a step back an re-think what you are doing. If you post example input and output, I'm sure a shorter way to accomplish what you are doing can be arrived at. Unless the 1st field in `"$line"` is a valid bash command, your command substitution followed by `eval` won't do what you think it does.

Comment: All great advice, I'd recommend that you also spend time using the shell debug-trace feature. `set -vx` will show you each line of code (as well as each block of code (loops etc) and then show you the line being executed (preceded with `+`) with all environment variables replaced with their values. `set +vx` to turn off) . Learn to isolate one-two lines of code (copy/paste into another terminal), to see what each command is doing and the output that it generates. AND copy/paste your code to https://shellcheck.net and fix any errors flagged there, be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` as first line.